# Splitting the page into different React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to Reactjs. I am super duper confused when it comes to splitting the page to different components. What should I consider when I divid the page into different components?

Comment: watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AbaV3nrw6E&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBuKtLgPR_zWYnrwv-JllpA) it will really help you

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is pretty much too broad of a question in my opinion. You can easily solve your problem by watching/reading tutorials. So is meant for solving specific problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to split into separate components, it becomes a bit of a challenge to share data between them. One way is for the parent to share state through props and actions to the children, but this ends up being messy, and your components depend pretty much on each other.

Most people do it using Redux, although you can do it with Observables  or mobX.